# C2011 'Node':'class' type redefinition

Tags: c++

I am implementing bptree using c++. I am am stuck in the initial step of node creation. Keep getting "C2011 'Node':'class' type redefinition" error. I found some suggestions online to remove class key word from cpp file. But when I remove class keyword I get lots of other errors. here is my code for Node.cpp:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>


using namespace std;


 class Node {
    bool leaf;
    Node** kids;
    map<int, string> value;
    int  keyCount;//number of current keys in the node

    //constructor;
    Node::Node(int order) {
        this->value = {};
        this->kids = new Node *[order + 1];
        this->leaf = true;
        this->keyCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (order + 1); i++) {
            this->kids[i] = NULL;
        }           
    }
};
```

and Node.h file is as following:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef NODE_HEADER
#define NODE_HEADER

class Node {

public:
    Node(int order) {};
};

#endif
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

In C++, headers are simply pasted into the body when you `#include`. So now the compiler sees:

```
class Node {

public:
   Node(int order) {};
};

// stuff from system headers omitted for brevity

using namespace std;

class Node {
  bool leaf;
  //...
};
```

There are two problems here:

1. compiler sees `class Node` twice with different bodies.
2. `Node::Node` is defined twice (first time empty `{}`).

## Solution

The header should include class **declaration**:

```
 #include <map>

 using namespace std;

 class Node {
    bool leaf;
    Node** kids;
    map<int, string> value;
    int keyCount;//number of current keys in the node

    //constructor;
    Node(int order);
};
```

Note that the constructor has no body here. It's just a declaration. Because it uses `map` you need to include `<map>` and add `using namespace` before the declaration.

After that don't put `class Node` again in the `.cpp` or `.cc` file. Only put the method implementations at the top level:

```
Node::Node(int order) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but when I delete class Node I get bunch of errors. After deletion of class Node It does not know any of Node's parameters such as value, kids and ect

Comment: Thank you, now that I did this I got errors in Node.h file that says: C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '<' C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int C2238 unexpected token(s) preceding ';' even though I have included #include<map> and #include<string>

Comment: Did you `#include <map>` and `<string>` before declaring `class Node` with `map<int, string> value` ?

Comment: I forgot to add using namespace std in my header file and main function in cpp file. Did those and it is error free. thank you so much

Comment: did you give me -1? really. would you undo it this vote makes me unable to post more question ...